# Do Mac or iOS IMAP passwords expire from the client side?

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave

I tried to log in to my 3rd party hosted (i.e. not Apple) IMAP email account this morning and got an authentication error. I then tried connecting on my phone and same thing occurred.

So, I contacted that host company’s support chat and was told to delete and re-create the account. I did it on the phone using the same password and all, and it worked.

The Mac Mail client still won't connect. The support person told me that the pw expired on the client side and that's why it won't connect.

I’ve never heard of that before and I've been using this same Mac, with Mac Mail connecting to multiple email accounts/servers and never had this happen before.

Is this just BS? And why/how would deleting and re-creating do anything different even if it was a server problem? I should probably let it go and get on with my life, but it's bugging me.

Answer (score 3):

Your IMAP password cannot expire on the client side. An [IMAP sever](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/imap/) was literally the forerunner to cloud based email like Gmail or Outlook.com; everything is handled by and through the server.

You authenticate to the IMAP server, not to a local IMAP client.  Only the IMAP server can expire your password.

> So I contacted that host co's support chat and was told to delete and re-create the account.

This is an old, old tech support trick.  When an error occurs, whether on your end or theirs (this was most likely on their end), they will have you delete your account and recreate it as it’s the easiest and most efficient way to resolve (not actually fix) the problem.  If they make a change that breaks your authentication, deleting the local profile and creating what amounts to a new one “fixes” things.

What was the problem?  We can’t know because it was “deleted” when you deleted your account.

Comment: Thanks. I did check the "log info" box on the Mac client and tried to see if there was anything decipherable in there, but nothing I could identify: